# How to create a powershell extension for my app

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm developing a platform and because it has a lot of configurations and parameters I thought that it would be very nice to allow System Administrator to script tasks and stuff like that, just like SharePoint does... And not only that: since I'll be the one administrating it for quite some time I don't really need (or have the time to build) a GUI, but I don't want to keep running tsql scripts like mad...

So my question is: How do I do that? How do I tell PowerShell that when someone enters `Get-MyAppTenants` he should invoke my DLL and execute the method `RetriveAllTenants()`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend writing a binary cmdlet since your going to use methods in a seperate library. You can write it in C# so you can use the skills you already have and just supply the PowerShell module with your application.

A startup guide can be found here:

[Building Binary PowerShell Modules – Part 1 – Getting Started](http://csharpening.net/?p=738)

[Building Binary PowerShell Modules – Part 2 – Design Principles and Other Guidelines](http://csharpening.net/?p=853)